# Delete an entry from MySQL from java

Tags: java

```
String name = tf1.getText();
b1.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e )
    {
        try
        {
            Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javaproject", "root", "noor1032" );
            PreparedStatement myStat = myConn.prepareStatement( "DELETE FROM user_info WHERE username=?" );
            myStat.setString( 1, name );
            myStat.execute();
            myConn.close();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "deleted" );
        }
        catch ( Exception f )
        {
            System.out.println( f );
        }
    }
} );
```

Can anybody tell me how to delete a full row in MySQL from java code by just entering the name of the person, a row contains other values as well like id, age,weight,etc... But I want to delete on the basis of name only.

Comment: your code should do exactly that.

Comment: The code may work if autocommit is enabled.

Comment: Code looks OK. Are you sure that there are no additional whitespaces in the name entered?

Comment: A few suggestions: Separate your database code from your Swing UI.  You can test it separately.  Print the entire stack trace.  Clean up your resources.